# SQL Injection Prevention in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I typically write my SQL as so in .NET

```
sql.Append("SELECT id, code, email FROM mytable WHERE variable = @variable ");
```

Then do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultConnection"]].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", myVariableName");
        ...
```

But should I also do this addParameter when the data I got comes directly from the database like so?

```
likesql.Append(string.Format("SELECT group_id, like_text FROM likeTerms ORDER BY group_id ASC "));

DataTable dtLike = SqlHelper.GetDataTable(likesql.ToString());

foreach (DataRow dr in dtLike)
{
    buildsql.Append(".... varId = " + dr["group_id"].ToString() + "...");

    ...
```

Is this acceptable? What is best practice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### You should always use parameters:

- Where are the values in your database coming from?
- Can you trust, in your example, that 'group_id' wasn't modified to be something you're not expecting?

#### Trust noone

Can someone with limited database access inject directly into a field used elsewhere?

#### Performance

Also, it helps performance. Cached execution plans will disregard the value of the parameter, meaning you're saving the server from recompiling the query every time the parameters change.

Comment: You need to give some justification for that view for this answer to be any good here.

Comment: Much better, I was going to mention the execution plan thing, but I won't bother now :)

Answer (score 5):

When you use DbCommands with parameters, the parameters are never "inlined" into the query. Instead, the query and the parameter data are passed to a special system stored procedure, sp_executesql. When it's done this way, whatever parameter data you have is treated as exactly that, and isn't parsed out of the query string; therefore, an injected command that may have gotten past your validation is never executed.

Using parameters is the best practice for ADO.NET-based data access layers, no matter where the data comes from, and is IMO the only way it should ever be done at this level (if you don't use an ORM). You should NEVER concatenate values you retrieve from a web or windows form into a SQL statement, and if you're follow that rule, why would you implement it any differently just because you're confident or even sure that the information isn't directly from the user? Follow the same pattern, and if and when you expose that method to persist user-specified data you won't get burned.

Comment: Doesn't really address OP's question. He was talking about parameterizing values from the DB, as opposed to (directly) from user input.

Comment: ORMs, or Object-Relational Mappers, are given information in some form that tells them how to translate or map an object, and any child objects it contains, to and from the rows in tables of the database. They then dynamically generate parameterized queries in ADO.NET. They don't care where the data they deal with comes from (they usually can't know); everything is passed into the query as a parameter so there are no surprises.

Answer (score 4):

It is acceptable (in sense if you know restrictions your may sometimes work correctly).

Is it good practice to use values from database and build SQL query with string concatenation - no.

I.e. in your sample what if "group_id" is `"'--"`?

Comment: so always use parameters then

Comment: Basically. My answer explains why, but his is short and sweet; the number of ways an attacker could still cause damage by injecting commands into a properly parameterized query is very small. The number of ways damage could be done by concatenating the same data into a query string are numerous.

Comment: I agree with you but only if group_id is a numeric field in the database, which the name suggests it is. This is because something like "'--" couldn't come out of a number field in SQL. If it's a text field then you've got all sorts of potential problems.

Comment: Yes you are both right but I will always use paramaterized SQL from now on regardless of where the data comes form. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using stored procedure, but this is acceptable
i also recommend that you sanitize your parameters before assigning them to the query

Comment: Why do you recommend stored procedures? Isn't that just an additional piece of "code" to maintain?