# Insert Data from a textbox into a database . c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, oop

Hello stack overflow you are my only hope, Its my first question here. I'm having problem with inserting things into a database from textboxes i searched throught it i tried everything it just doesnt work. Here is my code ->

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace E_BANK
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //objekti per konektim me DBne
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=desktop-ndocu0t\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MetinShop;Integrated Security=True");

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string accref = tb_accref.Text;
                        int deposit = Convert.ToInt32(tb_depamount.Text);
                        int psID = Convert.ToInt32(tb_personalID.Text);
                        string query = "INSERT INTO Bank1(accref, deposit, psID) " +
                "Values('" + accref + "', '" + deposit + "', '" + psID + "')";
                    }
                }
            }

            //mbylle lidhjen me DB
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Transition Updatet Sucessfully");
        }

        private void btn_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb_accref.Text = "";
            tb_depamount.Text = "";
            tb_personalID.Text = "";
            lblamount.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is your first question, please read [ask] - you will have to provide more detail than *"... it just doesnt work"*.

Comment: Sql Injection is not recommended as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484118/sql-injection-prevention-in-net)

Comment: Hello and welcome. As Filburt says some more information would be nice. what's the problem? where is it? do you get an exception? what exception do you get? There's your +1. Enjoy your stay at SO.

Comment: In your case the problem is quite obvious: You try to *insert* data by executing a *Reader*. Please take the time and read the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Really sorry guys but I have 1hr left to finish my project so thats why i need your help the exception says invalid object name - It can't recognize my table..

Comment: is that really ALL of your code?  seen to be reading data without asking for anything to be given to  you and creating an insert string without using it

Comment: Next to all your obvious errors, I highly doubt that your table is actually called ``Bank1``. I strongly believe you want to insert a row with the ``ID = 1`` into the table ``Bank``. Naming a table ``Bank1`` just seems too odd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert data to tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954871/insert-data-to-tables)

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
    private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=desktop-ndocu0t\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MetinShop;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Bank1 (accref, deposit, psID) VALUES (@accref, @deposit, @psID)", sqlConn))
            {
                if (sqlComm.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlComm.Connection.Open();
                string accref = tb_accref.Text;
                int deposit = Convert.ToInt32(tb_depamount.Text);
                int psID = Convert.ToInt32(tb_personalID.Text);

                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accref", accref);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deposit", deposit);
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@psID", psID);
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Transition Updatet Sucessfully");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it says exception incorrect syntax near Bank1

Comment: There was no spaces between Bank1 and the paranthesis '('.  I modified the code, Try this.

Comment: Is your database Case Sensible ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually run the INSERT command. Check out the [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the SqlCommand class.

Comment: command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); command.Connection.Close();

Answer (score 0):

EXECUTE Command missing

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //objekti per konektim me DBne
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=desktop-ndocu0t\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MetinShop;Integrated Security=True");

    conn.Open();

    string accref = tb_accref.Text;
    int deposit = Convert.ToInt32(tb_depamount.Text);
    int psID = Convert.ToInt32(tb_personalID.Text);
    //try all fields are string 
    string query = "INSERT INTO Bank1(accref, deposit, psID) Values('" + accref + "', '" + deposit + "', '" + psID + "')";
    //try last fields are numeric
    //string query = "INSERT INTO Bank1(accref, deposit, psID) Values('" + accref + "', " + deposit + ", " + psID + ")";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    //mbylle lidhjen me DB
    conn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Transition Updatet Sucessfully");

}

private void btn_reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb_accref.Text = "0";
    tb_depamount.Text = "0";
    tb_personalID.Text = "0";
    lblamount.Text = "0";
}

private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```